# Calc for responsive text is an invalid property

Tags: css, calc

I made an scss

```
@mixin responsive_font-size($viewport-min : "320px", $viewport-max: "1320px", $font-size-min:"16px", $font-size-max:"40px") {
    font-size:calc( #{$font-size-min} + (#{$font-size-max} - #{$font-size-min}) * ( (100vw - #{$viewport-min}) / ( #{$viewport-max} - #{$viewport-min}) ));

}
```

which suppose to give me a working code that limits font-size from 16px to 40px depending on the size of viewport.

However received css:

```
calc( 16px + (40px - 16px) * ( (100vw - 320px) / ( 1320px - 320px) ))
```

Is not working as suppose:

https://jsfiddle.net/maszynka/73toqgcx/

Any briliant ideas guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the CSS's `calc()` division must have a `<number>` on the right side. For that reason unit based values cannot be used in division like this.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) has great documentation on this.

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/maszynka/73toqgcx/3/).

Do you know why adding to px unit a value without unit works in calc? Like 16px + (21-9).

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN `calc()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

> **/**
>   Division. The right-hand side must be a `<number>`.

You are trying to divide a number by some amount of pixels. You have to use a number.

Maybe this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
font-size: calc(16px + (40 - 16) * ( (100vw - 320px) / ( 1320 - 320)));
```